# I can't understand this while loop code with try/except nested in (python)

Tags: python, while-loop

5.2 Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. Enter 7, 2, bob, 10, and 4 and match the output below.

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    try:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == "done" : break
        print(num)
        if num > largest:
            largest=num
        if num < smallest:
            smallest=num
    except:
        print("Invalid input")


print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)

desired output:                  my output:
Invalid input                    2 ← Mismatch
Maximum is 10                    4
Minimum is 2                     5
                                 maximum is 5(it prints the last input)
                                 minimum is None
```

I'm a total beginner at programming and python so if the error is obvious pls break it down as much as you could..thank you so much.

Comment: At no point in your program are you dealing with *numbers* - "10" is the smallest of your entries when dealing with strings, since they are compared character-by-character.

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns a string, so you need to cast the input to integer with `int()` before comparing it as a number. Also remove your unnecessary `print(num)`.

So change:

```
print(num)
```

to:

```
num = int(num)
```

Comment: Indeed. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question already explains what you want to do

> If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message

The explanation of why is that you need `int(num)` after you check for `done`, to *try* converting a string to an integer, and catch *exception* that happens for non integer inputs

I suggest you remove the try except, type anything but a number and observe the behavior

Comment: `int(input("..."))` will throw an error when the user types "done"

Answer (score 0):

The program will never reach `print("Invalid input")` since there is no error that could be thrown above. If you were to cast `num` to an integer with `num = int(num)` after you've checked `if num == "done"`, then the program would catch invalid inputs like "bob"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using strings, not numbers.  `10` is a number, it is stored as numeric data and you can do things like compare size, add, subtract, etc.  Specifically it is an integer, a number with no decimal places (computers store numbers in a lot of different ways).  `'10'` is a string, a set of characters.  Those characters happen to represent a number, but the computer doesn't know that.  As far as it can tell it is just text.

What you can do to convert a string to an integer is simply `num = int(num)`.  If the number can be converted to an integer, it will be.  If it can't, you will get an error.  That is why the instructions tell you to use a try/catch block.  It will catch this error.